# Layout is expanded when sent to phone

Tags: android, xml, layout, resize, center

I was wondering if I could get some help with a layout issue. Basically, I need three things (eventually more) to show up on the screen, and the middle on is doing it's own thing.

I need it to look like the following image (but with the space background shown on the other pictures):

[image]

But it looks like this (this is from a Nexus One AVD and my Galaxy Nexus phone):

[image]

That, or it shows the 'Please select which variables you already know' text about halfway down the screen. I have a main screen that shows fine. I've tried different layouts, different heights, manually entering heights and widths, I just can't seem to get it to work for me.

Here's the code for the 'broken' xml layout...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/app_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="28sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/recommend_instructions"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/app_name"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/recommend_instructions"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_submit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/button_submit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `RelativeLayout` has been able to get me close, but I was hoping that somebody would be able to look over my XML file and let me know if there's anything you can see that would be causing a re-size of the middle text. I've tried using a `gravity='center_horizontal'` with a placeholder layout to keep it at the top, but it keeps expanding. So I know that either the 'The Grand Unified theory' is expanding out to about the midway point and pushing down on it, or it's posting itself in the middle of the screen.

I thought it was the `gravity = 'center'` code I had earlier, but I changed that and it still did the issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Again, I'm hoping someone can help me figure out what is re-sizing my text code.

Comment: is this is your problem `text about halfway down the screen.` ??

Comment: also give the `android:textColor="#FFFFFF"` to `@+id/recommend_instructions`

Comment: `app_name` AFAIK is a pre-defined id when starting a new Android application, you should change this to `android:id="@+id/my_app_name"`. And change the referral id's appropriately.

Comment: @Asok `app_name` is a predefined string, not an id, so it should still be okay to use.

Comment: @DavidAndroidDev You're right, my mistake. I was referencing my `R.Java` and hadn't realized I was looking under `public static final class string`, good catch.

Comment: Hey, sorry for taking so long to reply. And yes M Mohsin Naeem, that is my problem, and I'm going to give the color to recommend_instructions eventually. I WILL try the app_name, as my app_name isn't just a predefined string, it's also an id. I realized this a bit late and swapped some naming schemes around, but it didn't fix anything.